# forEach for objects that match a criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I made this code for a game where when a player presses down arrow it looks through all the vehicles in a range of 100 and tries to open the closest. If the owner is the owner of that vehicle, it opens, else it returns an error. What I'm trying to do is just to make it look through all the vehicles that belong to the owner, so that even if the owner is closer to a vehicle that doesn't belong to him it still opens the closest vehicle that he opens. I've tried making an array with all his vehicles and executing the same code that I use to get all the closest vehicles, but it didn't work.

To get the closest vehicle from all the vehicles I used `closestVehicle = mp.vehicles.getClosest(player.position);`
and I tried using the same for the player's vehicles (returnVehicles): `closestVehicle = mp.returnVehicles.getClosest(player.position);`, but it isn't a function.

Any idea on how to do this? Or at least if the first vehicle doesn't belong to the player, get the second closest vehicle, and so on.

Full code:

```
function lockPlayerVehicle (player) {
    let vehicle = player.vehicle;
    if (vehicle) {
        vehicle.locked = !vehicle.locked
        if (vehicle.locked) player.outputChatBox(`Trancaste`);
        else player.outputChatBox(`Destrancaste`);
    }
    else {
        var returnVehicles = [];
        mp.vehicles.forEachInRange(player.position, 100, (vehicle) => {
                if(vehicle.ownerID == player.id) {
                    returnVehicles.push(vehicle); //MAKES AN ARRAY WITH ALL THE VEHICLES THAT BELONG TO THE PLAYER WHO PRESSED DOWN ARROW
                }
            }
        );
        player.outputChatBox(String(returnVehicles)) //RETURNS [object Object] 3 TIMES, WHICH MEANS THAT THE OBJECTS ARE INDEED BEING STORED.
        closestVehicle = mp.vehicles.getClosest(player.position); //IT GETS THE CLOSEST VEHICLE FROM ALL THE VEHICLES
        ownerID = closestVehicle.ownerID
        if (ownerID == player.id) {
            closestVehicle.locked = !closestVehicle.locked
            vehicleModel = String(closestVehicle.model)
            if (closestVehicle.locked) {
                player.call('vehicleUnlock', [vehicleModel, true]);
            }
            else {
                player.call('vehicleUnlock', [vehicleModel, false]);
            };
        }
        else {
            player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}Este veículo não é teu.`)
        }
    };
}
mp.events.add("keypress:DOWNARROW", lockPlayerVehicle);
```

Comment: So if the vehicles are in an array, I'd use filter and sort. Filter the array by vehicles the player owns and then sort the array by distance from the player. At that point, the first element in the array will be the one you want.

It looks like you are sort of already doing that with the forEachInRange part. So for getClosest, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Comment: remember to put ; at the end of the line, you missed it on at least 2 occassions. Also, I don't see the method getClosest() so I wouldn't know why it returns not a function.

Comment: Thank you both.
The method would be in the same place as the other one but with returnVehicles instead

Comment: @Leeish. Doesn't sort() just order the numbers from the smallest to the biggest? If so, that would only work if I was at 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Read further down on that page, you can put a compare function as the sort function. if you don't supply one yes, but you can make it sort how you want. array.sort(function(a,b){ if a.distance > b.distance return 1...} etc.